# Flexbox, have 2 items aligned left, a 3rd aligned right that stretches the full height of the container

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Is it possible to have 3 items in a flex container but have them displayed like this:

`1  3
 2  3`

Basically, where items 1 & 2 are on the left and about whatever height they each need to be, then item 3 is right-aligned but stretches the full height of the flex container?

Here's a codepen to illustrate: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RrORbj

Answer (score 2):

Here is a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wzhs07xe/1/) using flexbox.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="col">
    <div class="box one">
      one
    </div>
    <div class="box two">
      two
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <div class="box three">
      three
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

First, you set the container to a flexbox. Note, that the default value of `flex-direction` is `row` (horizontal). Setting the child element (`col`) with `flex: 1` makes the columns flexible in the direction of the parents `flex direction`.

Note also, that the default value of `align-items` on the container is `stretch`. What this does is set the height of all child elements (`col`'s) to the height of the tallest `col`.

```
.container {
    display: flex;             //make container a flexbox
}
.col {
    flex: 1;                   //make columns flexible (horizontally)
}
```

Next, we will use the same approach as before to spread box `three` vertically across the column.

```
.container {
    display: flex;
}
.col {
    flex: 1;         
    display: flex;             //make col a flexbox
    flex-direction: column;    //make the children of col flex vertically
}
```

Here we have added `display: flex` and `flex-direction: column` to turn column into a verticale flexbox. The last thing to do is make the box you want to be full height flexible vertically.

```
.three {
    flex: 1;                   //make it flexible
}
```

`.three` is flexible vertically (not the default horizontal) due to setting the flex direction on its parent.

EDIT:

Personally, I would set the class `box` to have `flex: 1` as shown in this updated [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wzhs07xe/3/). This allows any number of columns to flex vertically (while still allowing boxes of the "taller" column to grow as they need.